# Reference to pointer and reference overloading

Tags: c++

Can i call foo(const T*&) in the following situation?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void foo(const T*&)
{
    std::cout << "::foo(const T*&) \n";
}

template <typename T>
void foo(const T&)
{
    std::cout << "::foo(const T&) \n";
}
```

Comment: @jogojapan Try the following code - http://pastie.org/7982719

Comment: you try then ask for solutions in case of facing troubles

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov You need a `const int*`...

Comment: Your pastie compiles and runs fine - http://ideone.com/sFdik9 . Also tried on VC++.

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov Could you include the complete snippet in the question? Without the `main` part it's not quite clear where the problem lies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confused by the fact that `const T*&` means a reference to a pointer to `const T`, rather than a const-reference to a pointer to `T`.

To call that version of `foo`, use

```
int main()
{
  const int *iptr = 0;

  foo(i);
  return 0;
}
```

Alternatively (and probably as intended), change the function signature to `T *const &`, i.e. a const-reference to a pointer to `T`.

Comment: I must admit, at first I was confused too.

Comment: "const-reference", "const-pointer" are not the right terms here. First, a reference is _always_ "const" (in the sense that it must be initialized and can't be "re-bound" afterwards). Second, `const T*&` really means "a reference to a _pointer to const `T`_" (the _pointer_ is _not_ const, you can modify it to point elsewhere, but you can't modify the `T` _pointee_ through it). To be sure, write "const" to the _right_ of what it applies to, then read _right-to-left_: `T const*&` = "reference to pointer to const `T`". And so, `T *const &` is "a reference to a const pointer to `T`".

Comment: @gx_ Great. I've changed _const-pointer_ to _pointer to `const T`_ because that wording was really misleading. The term _const-reference_ is widely used, so I am not going to change that. Purists would want to call it a _const-qualified reference_.

Comment: How about replacing "rather than a const-reference to a pointer to T" with "... a reference of a constant pointer to a non-const T"?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't with that code, because there is an implicit conversion and you will end up calling the foo(const T&) version.
If you want to separate the two behaviours use explicit:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const T*&)
{
    std::cout << "::foo(const T*&) \n";
}

template <typename T>
void foo(explicit const T&)
{
    std::cout << "::foo(const T&) \n";
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    int *y=&x;
    foo(x);
    foo(y);
    return 0;
}
```

This way foo(x) will call foo(const T&), whereas foo(y) will call foo(const T*&)

Comment: I have never seen this way of using the `explicit` keyword. Is this C++?